# The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification: Cross-Threading issue?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter, timertask

I am attempting to edit a `ListView` on a regular interval using TimerTask:

```
public static TimerTask mTtRefreshUpload = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // Should create new adapter in here, not in Background Thread
                                refreshStatusItemAdapter = new RefreshStatusItemAdapter(context, R.layout.simple_list_item_upload, Constants.mLlItems);
                            }
                        });
            }
};
```

But I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has
>   changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the
>   content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but
>   only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls
>   notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes.

I have looked into the [documentation for TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html), but this has not helped.

What is the problem? Does it have to do with cross threading problems?

Comment: Yes, the timer task's run method runs on the background thread, so you need to use a mechanism such as runOnUiThread to push any UI work triggered from there back onto the UI thread.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? 

I am guessing by looking at your piece of code `refreshStatusItemAdapter` was already initialized and added to `ListView`.. is that right?

Comment: @Chris @Karthik : List view already set the adapter and show the data successfully. But even I initialized the adapter or call `notifyDataSetChanged` of adapter in runOnUIThread or Handler as above coding. I still get the error as above. Sometimes I get this error, not always.

Comment: The same problem I am experiencing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got same problem like you,

I think if you used `runOnUIThread`, it still always works for you.

Must define `runOnUIThread` in your `Constructor`, `onPreExecute`, `onPostExecute`.

Specially is your `ListView`, must define in `runOnUIThread` too.

*p/s : The last time, I forgot define `Initializing List View` in `runOnUiThread`.*